# Averaging in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I've trawled every forum prior to this question, so anyone with an answer will seriously save my bacon.

I'm trying to get an average of a column, but when I use AVG at the start of the expression the result I get is a much lower value than I'm expecting, as if its including lots of '0's it cant see. I can run two expressions that find the number of valid rows and the total of the numbers I want to average, but I cannot create a separate expression anywhere using those two values.

[Link to Google photos pic of SSRS expressions, etc](https://photos.app.goo.gl/YL4vvhCXVgYCYaHMA)

Any guidance on this is most welcome.

Comment: Can you post your AVG expression? If it is similar to the one you're using for SUM, then that is including the "NOTHING" values when the IIF condition returns 'false' which might affect the value in AVG.

Answer (score 0):

Its your `N/A` value in the `PE` row which causes the wrong calculation. Basically the `Avg()` function expects a numeric value. So it doesnt know what to do with a string `N/A`. You have to clear these values.

Go to your **Report Properties > Code > Custom Code** and add the following code:

```
Function ClearNAInInteger(strField as String) As Integer

IF strField = "N/A" Then
      Return 0
Else 
      Return CInt(strField)
End If

End Function
```

Now call your `Avg()` function like this:

```
=Avg(Code.ClearNAInIngeter(Fields!PrepEffort.Value))
```